# Photino Blazor app won't run in Program Files folder

Tags: visual-studio-2019, blazor

I've created a new Photino.Blazor app using the HelloPhotino template in Visual Studio 2019.
I can run this fine from my development folder. However it does not run when published to a Program Files folder.

Can anyone explain why this is so? Is it because files are downloaded and Program Files is read-only?

Comment: Do you see an error?  I copied my Photino project to c:\program files\<myproj> and ran it.  The app does run, but that app creates a folder and when it does it crashes.  That's because apps are not allowed to create a folder in \program files\.
Also note, it is a 64-bit app so it should be installed in \program files\ not \program files (x86)\ (which is a 32 bit directory). 
I then removed the code that creates the directory and ran it with no problem from program files directory.  What error do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh...I just re-read your sentence and I better understand your question...

You said: "Is it because files are downloaded and Program Files is read-only?"

That is indeed why the app will not run.  Your app cannot create folders or files in the \Program Files\ directory. It's a security issue that Microsoft does not allow.

Here's my experience with running a Photino app from \Program Files\ directory.

> I copied my Photino project to c:\program files<myproj> and ran it.
> The app does run, but that app creates a folder and when it does it
> crashes. That's because apps are not allowed to create a folder in
> \program files. Also note, it is a 64-bit app so it should be
> installed in \program files\ not \program files (x86)\ (which is a 32
> bit directory). I then removed the code that creates the directory and
> ran it with no problem from program files directory.

Comment: I didn't get to the bottom of this one. I'm currently migrating to a Maui Hybrid app.